Struggling with a While Loop
Here is my R code about a coin flipping game in which players keep flipping coins until their first tails (and then they are eliminated):
 num_players <- 3
 results <- data.frame(player = paste0("player", 1:num_players))
 status <- rep("playing", num_players)
 seen_tails <- rep(FALSE, num_players)
 round <- 1
 
 # simulation
 while (any(seen_tails == FALSE)) {
     
     coin_flips <- ifelse(runif(num_players) > 0.5, "heads", "tails")
     
     seen_tails <- ifelse(coin_flips == "tails", TRUE, seen_tails)
     
     current_round <- ifelse(status == "playing", coin_flips, "eliminated")
     

     status <- ifelse(seen_tails == TRUE, "eliminated", status)
     
     results <- cbind(results, current_round)
     
     colnames(results)[ncol(results)] <- paste0("round_", round)
     
     round <- round + 1
 }
 
 num_tails_last_round <- sum(results[,ncol(results)] == "tails")

The results look like this:
 > results
   player round_1    round_2    round_3
1 player1   heads      heads      tails
2 player2   tails eliminated eliminated
3 player3   heads      heads      tails

> num_tails_last_round 
[1] 2

I would like to modify my R code so that in the above case, an extra column would be added for round_4 in which all 3 players would are eliminated:
 > results
   player round_1    round_2    round_3  round 4
1 player1   heads      heads      tails eliminated
2 player2   tails eliminated eliminated eliminated
3 player3   heads      heads      tails eliminated

If the results of this simulation had looked like this, then I want to add a winner row is added:
 > results
   player round_1    round_2    round_3  round 4
1 player1   heads      heads      tails   winner
2 player2   tails eliminated eliminated eliminated
3 player3   heads      tails      tails eliminated

How can I do this?

I think this might work?
num_players <- 5
results <- data.frame(player = paste0("player", 1:num_players))
status <- rep("playing", num_players)
seen_tails <- rep(FALSE, num_players)
round <- 1

# simulation
while (sum(status == "playing") > 1) {
    
    coin_flips <- ifelse(runif(num_players) > 0.5, "heads", "tails")
    
    seen_tails <- ifelse(coin_flips == "tails", TRUE, seen_tails)
    
    current_round <- ifelse(status == "playing", coin_flips, "eliminated")

    status <- ifelse(seen_tails == TRUE, "eliminated", status)
    
    results <- cbind(results, current_round)
    
    colnames(results)[ncol(results)] <- paste0("round_", round)
    
    round <- round + 1
}

I added this code post simulation:
# if only one playr left playing, declare them as the winner
if (sum(status == "playing") == 1) {
    winner_index <- which(status == "playing")
    results[winner_index, ncol(results) + 1] <- "winner"
    results[-winner_index, ncol(results)] <- "eliminated"
    colnames(results)[ncol(results)] <- paste0("round_", round)
}

num_winners_last_round <- sum(results[,ncol(results)] == "winner")

Now it looks more logical:
> results
   player round_1    round_2    round_3    round_4
1 player1   tails eliminated eliminated eliminated
2 player2   heads      heads      heads     winner
3 player3   heads      heads      tails eliminated
4 player4   tails eliminated eliminated eliminated
5 player5   heads      heads      tails eliminated

> num_winners_last_round
[1] 1


The following function simulates in a different, I believe more efficient, way. It uses logical vectors playing and prev_round to determine which players are still playing. In the end it returns the previous run status.
sim <- function(nplayers) {
  # FALSE is 'tails' and the player is eliminated, 
  # TRUE is 'heads' and the player keeps playing
  # the game starts with all playing
  playing <- rep(TRUE, nplayers)
  round <- 0L
  while(any(playing)) {
    # save the current players' status (not playing/playing)
    prev_round <- playing
    round <- round + 1L
    coin_flips <- sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), replace = TRUE, nplayers)
    # eliminate the tails (FALSE)
    playing <- playing & coin_flips
  }
  list(round = round, count = sum(prev_round), winners = which(prev_round))
}

set.seed(2024)

num_players <- 1000L
R <- 10000L
res <- replicate(R, sim(nplayers = num_players), simplify = FALSE)

# this seems to be irrelevant, if the simulations are
# random then the winners change from game to game,
# commented out
# lapply(res, `[[`, 'winners')

# the games end in these many rounds
rounds <- sapply(res, `[[`, 'round')
hist(rounds)



# the number of winners in each simulation 
counts <- sapply(res, `[[`, 'count')
# and their frequencies
table(counts)
#> counts
#>    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11 
#> 7207 1775  629  242   86   28   18    7    5    1    2
# see the frequencies
table(counts) |> barplot()


Created on 2024-05-27 with reprex v2.1.0
